# Update with AddToSet not updating null value with MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using MongoDB, I'm having trouble adding en element to an Array when the array is null.  AddToSet works as expected if I add the item from the console. I am using the official C# driver from 10gen.

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", objectId);          
var itemDoc = item.ToBsonDocument();

//items is an array but currently null
var update = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.AddToSet("items", itemDoc); // YUNoWork?

//somefield doesn't exist
var workingUpdate = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.AddToSet("somefield", itemDoc); //works fine

var collection = DataBase.GetCollection<MyObject>(CollectionName);

collection.Update(query, update); // doesn't work
collection.Update(query, workingUpdate); // works
```

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there a more general way to add items to an array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did some digging, [according to some other comments](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/c9a5c1d9b9da62f6?pli=1) - like you say, if the element doesn't exist, it works, but if it's null - it doesn't work. Apparently this is by design.

One suggestion was to add the [BsonIgnoreIfNull](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/351f430e-5f7f-d97e-02e5-81b4f9c37d3f.htm) attribute to arrays, which will mean your AddToSet will then work.

Comment: Using BsonIgnoreIfNull for lists resolves the impedance mismatch between the C# class definitions and MongoDB. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else who sees this answer, you'll have to clean up your existing data for this to work. In other words, if you already have a document with a null property, you'll have to delete the property or the document. _Then_ this will work the next time you use AddToSet. I had added the attribute, but it still didn't work because the data had already been saved with the null.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of null value, put an empty array.