# Set subproperty on potentially null property in MongoDB in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

With MongoDB, using the C# driver, I need to construct an update for the property `x`

- that sets `x.y` to 42
- that works if `x` is null
- and that also works if `x` is already set to an object with other properties (in which case I need those properties to be retained).

In other words, I need to construct an update for the property `x` that sets `x.y` to 42 and that works simultaneously on the following two input documents:

```
{
  "x": null
}

should become

{
  "x": {
    "y": 42
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "x": {
    "z": 66
  }
}

should become

{
  "x": {
    "y": 42,
    "z": 66
  }
}
```

The naïve approach of doing

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("x.y", 42)
```

results in the error message

```
cannot use the part (x of x.y) to traverse the element ({x: null})
```

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution here is that you clean up your data so that the field is not null. You can use the [BsonIgnoreIfNull] on your property in your model to help stop null being set in the first place.

But to achieve this otherwise, you will need to perform 2 operations

The first to check that x is null, if it is not, perform the update on "x" (AddToSet), if it is then perform an update to set the entirety "x" (Set)

This is not tested, but for example:

```
var fb = Builders<YourObject>.Filter;

var idFilter = fb.Eq(f => f.Id, "");//Your filter otherwise you will be updating all documents
var nullFilter = fb.Eq(f => f.x, BsonNull.Value);//Filter to check x is set to null

var result = await Collection.Find(fb.And(idFilter, nullFilter))
.CountAsync()
.ConfigureAwait(false);

var toAppend = new BsonDocument("y", 42);

if (result > 0)
{
    var update = Builders<YourObject>.Update.AddToSet(f => f.x, toAppend);

    await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(f => idFilter, update).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
else
{
    var update = Builders<YourObject>.Update.Set(f => f.x, toAppend);

    await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(x => idFilter, update).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Here is another question that suggests the same thing:

[Update with AddToSet not updating null value with MongoDB C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917804/update-with-addtoset-not-updating-null-value-with-mongodb-c-sharp)

I hope this helps